# only one element tensors can be converted to python scalars

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, layer

```
def Log(A):
    '''
    theta = arccos((tr(A)-1)/2)
    K=1/(2sin(theta))(A-A^T)
    log(A)=theta K
    '''
    theta=torch.acos(torch.tensor((torch.trace(A)-1)/2))
    K=(1/(2*torch.sin(theta)))*(torch.add(A,-torch.transpose(A,0,1)))
    
    return theta*K

def tensor_Log(A):
    blah=[[Log(A[i,j]) for j in range(A.shape[1])] for i in range(A.shape[0])]
    new=torch.tensor(blah)
    
    return new

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

during training to get the outputs of my network, the above function is producing the following error, it is called inside a custom layer and I do not know what it is referencing, any thoughts?

Comment: What is the shape of the input of `tensor_Log` and `Log`?

Comment: @Ivan tensor_log is a 4 tensor while Log is just a matrix

Comment: @Ivan to be more specific tensor_Log is bs x extra dim x 3 x 3 and log accepts a 3x3 matrix

Comment: Ok, and which line exactly throws this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your list comprehension as `blah` is a list of list of tensors.

I would create a flat list of tensors by looping on `A.shape[0]` and `A.shape[1]` and then stack everything into a single tensor.

```
R = torch.stack([Log(A[i,j]) for i in range(A.shape[0]) for j in range(A.shape[1])])
```

You can then recover the desired format with `reshape` or `view`:

```
R.reshape(A.shape)
```

Comment: Cheers mate this fixed it. Weirdly enough I was using same sort of list comp on another function used in a custom layer and was not tossing error there

Comment: In this instance `Log` already returns a tensor so your list comprehension becomes a list of tensors which `torch.tensor` doesn't like to receive. If `Log` had returned a scalar it would have worked, maybe that's why it worked in your other function. I'm glad it helped ;).